# What are the tag names for icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty?

Tags: docker, open-liberty

I need to use the 23.0.0.3 or 23.0.0.4 builds of OpenLiberty as Docker image from icr.io/appcafe.

But `docker search icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty` (returns http status 404) does not work, and `icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty:23.0.0.4-full-java11-openj9` does not exist (using the naming convention for the previous versions)

And you cannot use `icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty:latest` as that is not stable and no repeatable builds can be created.

So what is the tagname for a Java 11 OpenJ9 based image?

Comment: does the flag from this url work? https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/container-images.html @Rudy De Busscher

Comment: The images in icr.io are based on UBI so have a -ubi suffix which your example doesn’t show. Maybe just add that suffix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images on icr.io are UBI based and they end with `-ubi`.  Therefore, the image is located at `icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty:23.0.0.4-full-java11-openj9-ubi`.

For a full list of available images, reference the [Open Liberty container images](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/container-images.html) page.

As a side note, `23.0.0.4-full-java11-openj9-ubi` is just a tag like `latest` and should not be used if you want to ensure repeatable builds.  Whenever you want to ensure the same container image is being used, you should always pin the image using the SHA256 digest of the image.  For example, for the above image, that would be `icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty@sha256:2e3e80c26892b29aa42b8f87f1827f59ae46fbad0df65413f6612e3650c5f84b`

Comment: Might be worth pasting the commands leading up to: `ibmcloud cr images --restrict appcafe/open-liberty` command from the link inline, within the answer here